# How to start contributing?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently a college junior student in computer engineering and really interested in robotics / hardware control via software and want to get into ROS. I have some experience with using Arduino, knowledge of some hardware design in logic level, and wrote some codes for a avionics control unit, yet I found jumping into ROS to be, a bit, overwhelming.

Can someone provide some starter help? Like, where to start with, how to start with, and when to consider contributing? I have configured environment and is going through tutorial.

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246706/how-to-start-contributing?/) by [UlyssesASL](https://answers.ros.org/users/28381/ulyssesasl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-10-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are some pointers for getting involved here: http://www.ros.org/contribute/ and some more detailed pointers here: http://wiki.ros.org/Get%20Involved

If you can find some ROS packages that you use, I'd suggest looking at open tickets for it, or consider identifying a new feature you'd like to see and submitting a pull request to make the change. If you start with small things you can get feedback during the review process and work your way up to larger changes.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1